# Rails 3 chained associations and scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have `Project` and `Entry` as models. Projects can have many entries, and entries belong to only a project. Entries have dates.

One reporting requirement is to show Projects that have Entries for a particular month. I have been successful in using scopes to achieve this, i.e. `Project.with_entries.on(param_the_month)`.

The issue is that I now want to display the entries for that month only, grouped by projects.
If I do `projects.each do |p|`, then query for the entries (`p.entries`), the returned entries are for all months, not just the month I specified.

While this is an obvious result, is there a way in Rails to simply return the entries for that month using my original chained scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has-many` associations also accept scopes, so you can do `projects.entries.your_scope` to filter them. The downside is that this would require another database query for every project, which might be slow depending on the size of your database.

An alternative that does not require extra queries would be to fetch the entries already filtered, and then go upward to get the projects:

```
entries = Entry.my_conditions.includes(:project)
entries_by_project = entries.group_by(&:project)
```

Now you have a hash whose keys are the projects, and the values are only the entries of that project that pass your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I did misunderstand :)

Take 2: You can merge scopes across models. So if you can create a `where`-type scope on `Entry` to select entries from a given month, you can then try something like

```
Project.with_entries.on(param_the_month).merge(Entry.on(param_the_month))
```

I've called it `on` by analogy with your scope on `Project` - without seeing your data model I can't say how exactly to implement it.

Comment: The with_entries returns projects that have entries, and 'on' is on another scope for projects

Comment: Well, if this solves the problem, then I haven't understood it correctly :) If a project has two entries, one that matches your conditions and one that doesn't, you want both entries or just the one that matches? I ask this because calling `#entries` on the return from the line above would return both entries.

Comment: @RenatoZannon No, it wouldn't. The neat thing about merged scopes is that calling `#entries` later doesn't trigger a new query - the collection is already populated with the matched records. So something like `Project.includes(:entries).merge(Entry.where(...))` means that when you call `#entries` on each returned `Project`, you only get the entries that matched. Give it a try!

Comment: @AndyH oh, you are right! I have tried it with `joins` instead of `includes`. I wonder if this behavior is intended, because I don't remember reading about it. Anyway, thanks for the cool trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can add includes into your scope, this way it will not query for those records again, it will eager load them when you use project scope.

```
scope :my_scope, includes(:entries).where( :active => true )
```